# "sfml-system.dll" is missing from your computer, error

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

I've been following the Code Blocks installation tutorial for SFML: http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/start-cb.php

I did everything in the tutorial, but when I compile, I get the error saying: 
"The program can't start because sfml-system.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I've been scouring Google for solutions, but nothing has worked so far. Stuff I've tried:
-Moving the sfml-system.dll into the same directory as my .exe
-Changing the "debug" linker options to static and dynamic.

Any help on this issue will be greatly appreciated, thanks!
Carpetfizz

Answer (score 2):

First, your link is for 1.6. The most recent version is 2, which might be better. (in terms of organization/ability etc - more time of improvements added to it in theory).

In the download of SFML I have had, the DLL's are in the SFML/bin folder, or something similar. When I have gotten this error before, it was when I was trying to link dynamically to them and the DLL was not, as you said, in the directory.

Ah. Assuming the directory is not the problem (you could try to put it right next to it just to be sure), looking at the tuturial in question says that you need to also define SFML_DYNAMIC. For some reason I feel like it said if you use gcc this did not make a difference, but that was probably the 2 tuturial (which might have different listed version of gcc), so I would try that. (near the bottom of the page).

Comment: Hi! Thank you soo much for your answer. The link I clicked for the SFML tutorial was from an out-of-date YouTube video. I have v2.0 set up, and followed the newest tutorial. Everything works fine! However, this tutorial didn't really go over how to set it up so that CB loads all the links whenever a project is created, like the last one did. It seems a tad bit tedious to re link all the libraries, every time I create a project. Also, this new tutorial prompted me to open an "empty project." This will also work in a console application right? Thanks much again!

Comment: If you mean to make it globally use the library rather than a per-project basis, you can go to settings -> compiler and debugger. In the global compiler options, it has the same options as in project build options (what libraries to link, search directories, etc), but they apply on a global scale - I am not certain, but it looks as though this applies to all build targets (debug and release), so using the SFML debug libs and the release libs would require some switching, if so.

Comment: I always use an empty project.  As far as I can tell, the only difference a console project does is make a main.cpp with a hello world example. I didn't find any libraries it links to otherwise, so it should work fine with SFML, as far as I can tell. Also, project -> properties (next to build options), within there you can set whether or not the console will open with the program (if you don't want it to, select GUI). Note that you can open SFML windows either way.